# Port conflict issues

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp, port

I spent some time for the ports used by jvm on krt boxes. I see each jvm opens 10 ports.
Five are defined in the command line for mgmt., http, debug, jmx and ajp. Out of the other 
five I can understand  1 for activemq and  2 for jdbc. There are two unknown to me 
One out of that connects back to the server and another does not show what it is listening 
To. The one option I read on net it to increase the range of ephemeral ports (we have 32k
Starting we can go 16k)  I am not sure how we can dictate the port numbers for the five
Which are not defined today

Some commands to describe the situation.

```
[krtdev7@surya:/env/krtdev7/bin]$krtport KRTDataHistory-1
PORT ASSIGNMENTS:
=================
mgmt/shutdown=17091
http=17291
ajp=17491
jmx=17691
debug=17891

[krtdev7@surya:/env/krtdev7/bin] $ netstat -ap|grep 16831
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17291           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16831/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17491           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16831/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36691           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16831/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40596           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16831/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17691           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16831/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:17091         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16831/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17891           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16831/java
tcp        0      0 surya.internal.su:51631 sky.internal.s:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 16831/java
tcp        0      0 surya.internal.su:40938 agni.internal.sun:61616 ESTABLISHED 16831/java
tcp        0      0 surya.internal.su:51630 sky.internal.s:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 16831/java
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16386441 16831/java**
```

Now we can see the 5 extra ports are assigned Could anybody let me know how to control these 5 extra port assignment rather how to make the jvm choose from the range of ports for these 5 extra ports?

Comment: You can't make any process choose dynamic ports from a restricted range, and there is no reason to do so. This is one of the fantasies entertained by some netadmins who think that defining rules for outbound is a useful occupation. It isn't.

Comment: But I am facing the problem when I am deploying another application and fixed port for that particular  application is already occupied by the previous application.

Comment: So you are trying to use a fixed port from the dynamic port range. So don't. Use a fixed port from the non-dynamic range. Don't expect to be able to break every other piece of software just because of a poor choice in your own.

Comment: OK. got it. I am wrong,  Thank you for your response.